# How to push element in empty array in map key

Tags: javascript, dictionary, for-loop

```
var findJudge = function(N, trust) {
   const map = new Map()
   
   // Map should be Element, []
   for(let i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
       if(!map.has(i)) {
           map.set(i, arr = [])
       }
   }
   
   //Map [] should be filled with trusted
   for(let i = 0; i < trust.length; i++) {
       if(map.has(trust[i][0])) {
           map.set(trust[i][0]), map.get(trust[i][0]).push(trust[i][1])
       }
   }
   console.log(map)
};
```

On the second for loop, I'm trying to figure out how to push new elements into key

right now looks like 1 -> [], 2 -> []

trying to loop through the array get index 1 from each trust and add to the map

Can I not fo it this....

do I need to make an Obj and do it without new Map()

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why not just create the array you want *then* set it into the map?

Comment: that's what I ended up doing, but is that the only way to add to the map? 

I can't simply creat for-loops to push multiple values into the key pair values -> []

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, and without knowing what your data actually looks like, it's difficult to help. There's certainly no reason to continually set the map entry, you can push directly to the entry's array. (Noting that it's not clear why you're using the comma operator in your second loop.)

Comment: that is a very strange line with the comma operator. are you aware that comma is *not* separating function arguments to `map.set` because you've closed the function call just before it?

Comment: some sample data and what you expect out of this would be very helpful, if they're staying empty it's possible `if(map.has(trust[i][0]))` never is true, which could be the case depending on your data

Comment: map.set(trust[i][0]), map.get(trust[i][0]).push(trust[i][1])... I was trying get the value and trying to push element into the []... like arr.push() ... I guess the conclusion is. I can't keep adding new values to an empty array in a new Map and just make an array and set it in the map...

Comment: Your question and problem aren't very clear.